# Problem CorePlot in iPhone framework

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-plot

I have followed the documentation of CorePlot. After doing everything, I am facing following problem:

```
error: 'CPLayerHostingView' undeclared (first use in this function)

 error: 'hostingView' undeclared (first use in this function)

 error: expected expression before ')' token

 error: object cannot be set - either readonly property or no setter found

 error: object cannot be set - either readonly property or no setter found

 error: object cannot be set - either readonly property or no setter found

 error: object cannot be set - either readonly property or no setter found

 error: object cannot be set - either readonly property or no setter found

 error: object cannot be set - either readonly property or no setter found
```

What might be the problem ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Core-Plot: Unknown class CPLayerHostingView in Interface Builder file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431187/core-plot-unknown-class-cplayerhostingview-in-interface-builder-file)

Answer (score 1):

The name has changed: `CPLayerHostingView` is now `CPTGraphHostingView`. This change was effective in release 0.4 for iOS and MacOS for later releases.