# add an Xcode project to an existing one

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I want to combine two Xcode projects into one app. I have project-one which is working fine and project-two w/c is also working fine. project-one is more like of an ebook gatherer and project-two is the ebook reader. The two works fine separately. I drag and drop project-two into project-one and add project-two as dependency for project-one. I get no errors when building the app and It runs normally until I open a tab(the whole app is a tabbarcontroller).
I have a 'books' tab and when I tap this, I want to run project-two in this tab. I tried calling the nib from project-two to load when the 'books' tab is tapped but it gives me a warning 'Unknown class RootViewController in Interface Builder file.'. So how can I successfully link the two projects so I can load project-two in my 'books' tab?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Despite the "Unknown class MyClass in Interface Builder file." error printed at runtime, this issue has nothing to do with Interface Builder, but rather with the linker, which is not linking a class because no code uses it directly.
[“Unknown class  in Interface Builder file”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725881/unknown-class-myclass-in-interface-builder-file-error-at-runtime)

Comment: I already added the flags in my build settings but still the problem persist.

Comment: any help? :( been stuck on this for quite some time now.