# UICollectionView doesn't contain UICollectionViewCell in IB

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, ios6, uicollectionview

I'm trying to add a UICollectionView to a .nib file in IB. I've worked through a few tutorials and had no problems.

In my existing app, when I drag a collection view into a view in IB and then expand the object, the CollectionView Flow Layout is there , but there is no collection view cell. I also cannot drag and drop a cell into the collection view. Also the collection view is displayed differently, showing an image of a grid of cells instead of the normal white box.

I've tried creating a new view controller with nib, and have the same results when adding a collectionView.

This app WAS targeting iOS 4.2, but I've changed the deployment target to iOS 6.

In any newly created projects I don't get this behavior.

Comment: OK, it seems that you can only layout a UICollectionView completely using IB inside a storyboard. In a .nib you get the behavior I described above. In a storyboard, you get the UICollectionViewCell with your UICollectionView. What's up with that???

Comment: having this same issue as well, rather annoying

Comment: Even in storyboard, you cannot drab and drop the collection view cell into a collection view object. Not sure why.

Comment: i have this same issue.

Answer (score 9):

I can't tell you why it does not work, but for me the subclass approach from this blog post solved the problem:

http://www.adoptioncurve.net/archives/2012/09/a-simple-uicollectionview-tutorial.php

here is a short summary:

- create a new class MyViewCell which extends UICollectionViewCell and create properties, actions, outlets and methods as needed.

`@interface MyViewCell : UICollectionViewCell`

- create a View (xib file) with a Collection View Cell as its root object (and delete the object which is created by default).
- in the attributes set the custom class of this Collection View Cell to your extended class MyViewCell (instead of the default UICollectionViewCell).
- in the attributes under Collection Reusable View define an Identifier, e.g. myCell, you will need this later to register your call.
- go back to your custom class and modify the inithWithFrame method to load and use your created view.

  ```
  - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame 
  { 
     self = [super initWithFrame:frame]; 
     if (self) 
     { 
       // Initialization code 
       NSArray *arrayOfViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CVCell" owner:self options:nil];

       if ([arrayOfViews count] < 1) { return nil; }

       if (![[arrayOfViews objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[UICollectionViewCell class]]) { return nil; }

       self = [arrayOfViews objectAtIndex:0];
     }
     return self;
  }
  ```
- then you can register this class to be used by the collectionView with

`[self.collectionView registerClass:[MyViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"myCell"];`

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I have added more details to the answer.

Comment: Awesome! Just don't forget to register collectionView:

     [self.collectionView registerClass:[MyViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"myCell"];

Answer (score 9):

It's been a while since the question has been asked but I faced the same issue lately.

Eventually, I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184968/uicollectionview-adding-uicollectioncell).

In short:

- You cannot drag and drop a UICollectionViewCell into a UICollectionView if you are in a .xib file. This is only possible in a storyboard.
- The workaround is to create a .xib file for your custom cell and to register the cell manually using:

  `[self.collectionView registerClass:[CollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:CELL_ID];`

Comment: This is still an issue on Xcode 8.2.1. I think we have to use the workaround forever.

Comment: For the workaround, I have to use registerNib, or else the dequeueReusableCell is just an empty view, without any information configured in xib.

Answer (score 3):

Define your cell view in a separate nib file. The view must be of type `UICollectionViewCell` or a subclass.

Then, you must register the nib with your collection view:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyNib" bundle:nil];
    [self.collectionView registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
}
```

Comment: for some reason this does not work. when dequeueing the cell, an exception is thrown: "nib must contain exactly one top level object which must be a UICollectionReusableView instance". this is really strange, since the documentation states "The nib file must contain only one top-level object and that object must be of the type UICollectionViewCell".

Comment: UICollectionViewCell inherits from UICollectionReusableView.

Answer (score 0):

While these answers are correct, the underlying cause of the problem is quite subtle and Apple needs to update their error message in the log.  When you see:

```
Unknown class MyViewCell in Interface Builder file.
```

What it actually means is that your source code is missing the **@implementation** declaration or that the .m file has not been added to the target.  So check your code and make sure you have:

```
@implementation MyViewCell

@end
```

**This is true for both UITableViewCell and UICollectionViewCell.**

I discuss the problem further at https://stackoverflow.com/a/12755891/539149 for the general case.

The interesting thing is that if you are missing the **@implementation** and call:

```
[self.myCollectionView registerClass:[MyViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyViewCell"];
```

You will see:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MyViewCell", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MyViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

So Apple knows about the problem, they just aren't detecting it during compilation.  I would advise against putting custom cells in separate nibs or calling registerClass: forCellWithReuseIdentifier:.  It's much cleaner to store the custom cell inside of its container UICollectionView or UITableView in Interface Builder.