# Impossible add Cell to UICollection View

Tags: xcode5

I try to add the object "Collection View Cell" inside the object "Collection View" with the Interface Builder but it is impossible.

I work with nib files (Not Storyboard). When I drop the object "Collection View Cell" the editor will not let me.

I work with XCode 5.0.2, and the project is developed for iOS 6.0 and later.

I have the Apple sample code "CollectionView-Simple" and I try to do the same.

Someone has been in the same situation?

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

[UICollectionView doesn't contain UICollectionViewCell in IB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12790902/uicollectionview-doesnt-contain-uicollectionviewcell-in-ib)

The sample code (Download Zip file):

https://github.com/timd/CollectionViewExample