# Interface Builder loading wrong class

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, interface-builder, static-libraries

I created a custom `NSTextView` subclass called `JWTextView`. It's part of a separate Xcode project. That project has a target that creates a static library containing this class. I now added this subproject to my main project under `MainProject/Libraries/JWKit` (in Finder) and added it in Xcode as well. I made my main project's target depend on the subproject's library target and I'm linking the library in my main target. I also added `MainProject/Libraries/**` to the Library and Header search paths.

Now I'm trying to use this view in my main project. I added an `NSTextView` to one of my xib's and changed its class to `JWTextView`. I also have an `IBOutlet JWTextView` in my code and call some methods on it upon user interaction. `JWTextView.h` is imported. Everything compiles file.

But once I call a method on this text view that I implemented in my `JWTextView` subclass, the app crashes with an **unrecognized selector** error:

```
-[NSTextView myCustomMetod:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x101901a80
```

I checked, and it's actually an `NSTextView` instance, even tough the ivar is a `JWTextView` and I set the class in IB.

If I just add the classes to my main project it works fine, but not as a subproject and a static library.

Comment: Found a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725881/unknown-class-myclass-in-interface-builder-file-error-at-runtime

Answer (score 0):

The compiler optimized it out, because I wasn't referencing the class anywhere by name (except the ivar, which doesn't seem to help).

Adding `[JWTextView class];` to `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` fixed the problem.

Comment: How about using the `-ObjC` linker switch instead of your workaround when linking your library into the application target?