# Can't load sub-view class and xib from static library and bundle

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have 2 iOS projects. Let's call them A and B. A is library project including 2 products:

- a static library
- and bundle file has some .xib files

B is an app project using project A's library and bundle files.

Project A has 2 things: a table (customized UIViewController class and a .xib file) and a cell (customized UITableViewCell and .xib file)

The problem is:

Project B can load the table from library and bundle, but can't load cell for that table.

This is an open-source project, I am stuck for a few days, please help me out.
https://github.com/G3Feng/granpost-ios

Error:

```
2013-09-18 07:28:50.184 TabbedDemo[34408:c07] |cell| load bundle:NSBundle </Users/Feng/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/359F9352-F3BA-4478-AA51-A182D8CFA4AA/TabbedDemo.app/GPResource.bundle> (not yet loaded)
2013-09-18 07:28:50.185 TabbedDemo[34408:c07] Unknown class articleListCell in Interface Builder file.
2013-09-18 07:28:50.204 TabbedDemo[34408:c07] Could not load the "commentbubble-01.png" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "(null)"
2013-09-18 07:28:50.206 TabbedDemo[34408:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UITableViewCell 0x71598b0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key bottomBar.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c97012 0x10d4e7e 0x1d1ffb1 0xb80e41 0xb025f8 0xb020e7 0x68f23 0xb2cb58 0x236019 0x10e8663 0x1c9245a 0x234b1c 0x2368da 0x39a0 0xd38fb 0xd39cf 0xbc1bb 0xccb4b 0x692dd 0x10e86b0 0x2293fc0 0x228833c 0x2288150 0x22060bc 0x2207227 0x22a9b50 0x2eedf 0x1c5fafe 0x1c5fa3d 0x1c3d7c2 0x1c3cf44 0x1c3ce1b 0x1bf17e3 0x1bf1668 0x18ffc 0x2b1d 0x2a45)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one solved the problem finally: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6092090/1571946

==>

This doesn't really have anything to do with Interface Builder, what's happening here is the symbols aren't being loaded from your static library by Xcode.

To resolve this problem you need to add the `-all_load -ObjC` flags to the `Other Linker Flags` key the Project (and possibly the Target) in the `Build Settings`.

Answer (score 0):

Check every time you access a resource from another bundle. Try this code.

```
NSBundle *yourBundleObject = [NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"yourBundleIdentifier"];
if(![yourBundleObject isLoaded]){
   [yourBundleObject load];
}
```

Comment: I think it is using the right bundle, if you try to build , you will get details. Code: NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"GPResource" withExtension:@"bundle"]];

Comment: The problem here is that, it's using the right bundle, but that right bundle may not have been loaded yet. Thus, you need to check if it's not loaded, if so, then load it:
if(![yourBundleObject isLoaded]){
        [yourBundleObject load];
    }

Comment: That is partial reason. With [bundle load], it still has problem with Unknown class articleListCell in Interface Builder file.