# Unknown class <MyClass> in Interface Builder file in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder

I am programming the ToDoList Objective-C Tutorial from Apple, but try to do it in Swift.
([Tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/SecondTutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH8-SW1))

Now that I am ready, when I run the Application, I get the error:

> Unknown class AddToDoItemViewController in Interface Builder file in Swift.

In [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874634/how-unknown-class-myclass-in-interface-builder-file-error-can-be-fixed-with), somebody solved a, as I think similar Problem with `[MyClass class]` in Objective-C. Is there a similar way to do this in Swift?

Comment: Do you have a Swift class named `AddToDoItemViewController`?

Comment: I ran into a similar issue (Xcode 6 Beta 6). I had a view controller (in a storyboard) with a custom class. This was discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924966/xcode-6-strange-bug-unknown-class-in-interface-builder-file @grfs's answer (accepted answer at time of writing) worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar line in swift would be `AddToDoItemViewController.self`. All that really matters is you call your view controller from swift code so the linker knows to include that file.

Comment: thanks for your help. But somehow this doesn't solve the problem... Where do I have to insert this code. Allways get the error: expected declaration.

Comment: You can add it almost anywhere. An easy place to put it would be in AppDelegate inside `func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool`

Comment: @connor Rather than having to reference the class in code, surely it's not the default for the linker to optimize out these classes? Is it possible this is similar to a missing "-all_load -ObjC" issue? ie. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6092090/88111

Answer (score 38):

I found that on a lot of my Swift Controllers there's a new Module Option which was set to None
[image: Failure]

So to fix it just set the Class to a different one and then set it back. That gave me this

[image]

Comment: +1 This happened to me after renaming a module (had the old module name explicitly set). I corrected it the same way.

Comment: I do that, but the Module never changes. It doesnt change when I change the Class to a different one, and it doesnt change when I put it back to the proper one. :(

Comment: You are a fakin master! 10x a bunch.

Comment: Working solution. This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this situation when I made a mistake and used a different name in the @OBJC statement than my declared class name.