# Load Storyboard From Framework

Tags: ios, iphone, frameworks, storyboard

I get this error

```
[<UIViewController 0x8ab1f80> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: 
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key
```

when I load my storyboard from a bundle. I have a label connected from my storyboard to the controller. But when I disconnect it, it works fine.

The solutions given here works '[iOS - Linking framework storyboard to ViewController for use in main project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19954771/ios-linking-framework-storyboard-to-viewcontroller-for-use-in-main-project)' but I cannot set it as I have another framework in my bundle. I have added the storyboard in my `info.plist`, still not working. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You say the problem goes away when you disconnect the label from your controller. How are you connecting it? What property are you connecting it to?

Comment: yea when i disconnect the label, it works fine. I connect it from storyboard (new referencing outlet)to the controller.h file.

Comment: I set 'other link flags' to -ObjC and it works fine.