# iOS unale to access the story board that was presented in embedded framework

Tags: ios, ios8, ios-frameworks

I want to achieve the following things:

1. I created a embedded framework and inside that framework i created
   one story board with single view controller.
2. I created a one view controller inside that embedded framework and
   trying to access the story board from that view controller but my app crashed when ever am trying to access the story board.

Any idea how can i access the story board that was in the embedded framework?. Any help that might be appreciate.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19954771/ios-linking-framework-storyboard-to-viewcontroller-for-use-in-main-project

Comment: David Kaszas, That answer is completely different from my issue. Because am trying to access the story board from the ios8 shared embedded framework. The above link constructed the framework was not ios8 style embedded framework.