# Adding one Xcode project into other and make it a single project?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-project

*I made a good research on this but things failed and in need of help.*

When the project started I was the only one working with the project later then another employee has been recruited by our employer to join the project. As we both were new to iOS development we both created new project and started working with that keeping in mind that we could easily merge both the projects into  a single module. I have added the second project created by the new employer by dragging and dropping it to project that I have created.but on this code

```
let _notesViewController = _storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AllNotesViewController") as! AllNotesViewController
```

an error says **use of undeclared type 'AllNotesViewController**
'
*'AllNotesViewController'* is in the second project that I have added into my project. What went wrong ??? Why that error ??? How can I merger two projects into one ???

Comment: i think you have caused yourself a world of pain by doing it this way, the only way this will work if the one project is considered a framework to the other project, if you have used storyboards etc in both projects you will have to do some stuff to get them to work as [described here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19954771/ios-linking-framework-storyboard-to-viewcontroller-for-use-in-main-project/19957367#19957367)

Comment: if you want to save yourself some trouble i would just copy the files from the one project into the other and make it a single project, if that is what it was meant to be in the first place... not sure what your requirements are though

Comment: and once that is done, definitely use some version control like git so that both of you can work on the project at the same time if you are not using it already

Comment: @MuhammadAdnan I have initiated the storyboard with secondproject's storyboard.

Comment: @Fonix  like you said there is storyboard in both projects. I will try your method. and one help You said copy the files and do I need to copy all the files from project folder ?  any problems with constraints on copying??? After this we will be using github  ...

Comment: you wouldnt need to take every file, but just your code files and storyboards really, could be some other things but i guess the compiler will shout at you and tell you wants missing. probably would need to merge your assets folder as well. Make sure everything under build phases in your project settings has all the newly copied stuff in there as well

Comment: @Fonix tried copying files but got an error and it say's Multiple error occurred while copying the file