# Xcode: libpods.a is red

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

[image: libpods.a]

Does anyone know why this is? I'm using SWRevealViewController.  It has been working up until this point.  I'm using the workspace, and I've already looked into other articles and nothing has worked so far.  It's not pulling up an error, but when I run the program it won't load anything because SWRevealViewController is the first thing that comes up.

Thoughts?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725881/unknown-class-myclass-in-interface-builder-file-error-at-runtime

this answered my question.  Sneaky apple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you get an error message when you try to compile? I've had libPods.a in red before, but that didn't stop my project from working. If I remember correctly, this used to be some kind of display bug back in previous versions of Xcode.

Comment: it's really really odd.  I don't get any warnings or errors and the thing builds fine but none of my pods show up in the program and it says "Unknown class SWRevealViewController in Interface Builder file."

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Interface Builder doesn't know about your pods, and that's is an expected behaviour.

Comment: I am getting often whenever I try to update pod for Braintree, Facebook SDK 3.24. Any thought to fix?