# CocoaPods - Red Frameworks?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa, cocoapods

So I've been digging around all night trying to figure out how to fix these red frameworks, I'm going to use this as another resort!

Pods.framework is red, Foundation.framework is red. I followed all the instructions and it seems to have imported all correctly except for this.

I really just want to figure out how to fix these red frameworks. Even though the app still runs, I'm scared for the future if it crashes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode: libpods.a is red](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24139873/xcode-libpods-a-is-red)

Answer (score 3):

Check step by step instruction [guide](http://cocoapods.org/)  of how to install pods in system and project .

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to this Tutorial Its explain step by implementation of the cocoa pods.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/64546/introduction-to-cocoapods-2

Thanks
Sandeep

Comment: could this just be a bug in xcode, because my project compiles fine?

Answer (score 2):

Updating my pod resolved this problem for me:

```
pod update
```