# Interface Builder is allocating a custom view as a regular UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder

Edit #3: I somehow missed a second console message the 10 times I ran this, keeping me puzzled about this. It's a known problem that's been solved. I need "-all_load -ObjC" set as a linker flag, and I don't know why it wasn't already like that. See ["Unknown class <MyClass> in Interface Builder file" error at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725881/unknown-class-myclass-in-interface-builder-file-error-at-runtime)

I'm trying to use an `FBLoginView` (part of the Facebook SDK framework), a subclass of `UIView`, in my storyboard and set a property on it in `viewDidLoad` in the view controller for its superview.
This is what I have:
[image: IB and code]

The UIView (grey box) shown has its class set to `FBLoginView`, as you can see. It's linked to the property `loginView` in my view controller .m on the right.

In `viewDidLoad`, it does `_loginView.readPermissions = @[@"user_friends"]`, which causes the program to crash. Edit #2: The log says:

```
App became active.
Unknown class FBLoginView in Interface Builder file.
-[UIView setReadPermissions:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10c120b90
```

I set a breakpoint, and `loginView` is a `UIView`, not an `FBLoginView`. This doesn't make sense; I already changed it to `FBLoginView` in Interface Builder. How do I fix this?

Edit: Here is the connections inspector for the view controller in IB:
[image]

Comment: sounds strange, do you have an IBOutlet to your FBLoginView?

Comment: You've shown that you have an `FBLoginView`.  Now select the view controller in the storyboard, press Command-Option-6 to show the Connections inspector, and post a screen shot of that inspector.  Also, are there any other messages in the debug console?

Comment: @Injectios Yes, it's in the .m to the right. Sorry, the uploader shrunk my screenshot and made it harder to see.

Comment: @robmayoff I've edited my question to include the screenshot. I don't know why it's saying that it's connected to Login View… I didn't name anything in my project that. And yes, there IS another message in the console that I somehow didn't see, or it wasn't there before. "Unknown class FBLoginView in Interface Builder file."

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Unknown class <MyClass> in Interface Builder file" error at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725881/unknown-class-myclass-in-interface-builder-file-error-at-runtime)

Answer (score 0):

Some things to try:

- Duplicate your FBLoginView class with a different name and try that.
- Double check the spelling of your FBLoginView class name - check the file names for your .m and .h, and then check the interface/implemenation in the actual files to make sure it's capitalized correctly.

Comment: It's definitely the correct spelling, and it even worked when I did this a similar way in another project (except without a storyboard). FBLoginView.h is part of FacebookSDK.framework.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure `FBLoginView.m` is declared as your current build target member (e.g. compile sources).
To do that, select `FBLoginView.m` in Project Navigator, see "Target Membership" section in the File Inspector as attached screenshot(deleted).

**Edit:**

You should read [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.1#login-button) :)
See the bottom of "Adding the login UI control" section.

You must add `[FBLoginView class]` in `- application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` AppDelegate method OR add the `-ObjC` flag to your linker options.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have an FBLoginView.m anywhere since I just imported it from FacebookSDK.framework, which contains headers and the compiled library, but I checked, and the framework does have the correct target membership.