# class selector in Facebook login in IOS

Tags: ios, facebook

I followed the instructions on http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-facebook-login-sdk/

It works, but magically

I don't understand this

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    [FBLoginView class];
    [FBProfilePictureView class];

    return YES;
}
```

What does sending the class message to these classes do? I don't find it in the facebook ios documentation

Comment: did you try removing them? they shouldn't do anything, calling `class` on an object only returns the object's class but it shouldn't have any side effects.

Comment: It's probably used to "wake up" the classes, causing them to run their `initialize` class methods.

Comment: so it does manual lazy instantiation?

Comment: Could it be linked to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725881/unknown-class-myclass-in-interface-builder-file-error-at-runtime) ? I'm not sure calling the "class" method is supposed to trigger any initialize method is it ?

Comment: It might be related. If you set a UIView's class to FBLoginValue in Interface Builder, but never use the class FBLoginValue in your code, it could generate a linker error at runtime, saying “Unknown class FBLoginValue in Interface Builder file”.

Answer (score 0):

Calling anything on an `NSObject` has the side effect to call the lazy [`initialize`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/nsobject/1418639-initialize) method once.

That's how `FBLoginView` is doing its magic. It would have work with `[FBLoginView self];` too.