# Send in app email in Swift

Tags: ios, email, swift

Having trouble doing this in Swift..Super easy in Objective C. The error I get in the log is this:

```
2015-01-31 22:16:58.734 fun facts[15208:623304] Unknown class Settings in Interface Builder file.
2015-01-31 22:17:10.783 fun facts[15208:623304] -[UIViewController sendEmail:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9b7bc2fa30
2015-01-31 22:17:10.794 fun facts[15208:623304] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController sendEmail:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9b7bc2fa30'
```

See my code below. Any ideas what I do wrong?

```
//////////////////////SEND EMAIL


    @IBAction func sendEmail(sender: AnyObject) {

        var emailTitle = "Test Email"
        var messageBody = "This is a test email body"
        var toRecipents = ["yolo@mail.com"]
        var mc: MFMailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mc.mailComposeDelegate = self
        mc.setSubject(emailTitle)
        mc.setMessageBody(messageBody, isHTML: false)
        mc.setToRecipients(toRecipents)

        self.presentViewController(mc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }



    func mailComposeController(controller:MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result:MFMailComposeResult, error:NSError) {
        switch result.value {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled.value:
            println("Mail cancelled")
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved.value:
            println("Mail saved")
        case MFMailComposeResultSent.value:
            println("Mail sent")
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed.value:
            println("Mail sent failure: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        default:
            break
        }
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
}

}
```

Comment: Check that you have set your custom view controller class for your scene in Interface Builder

Comment: What is the class you are sending the email from called?

Comment: @Paulw11 From the error message, it looks like he has tried to.

Comment: But the error message says something about the `UIViewController` superclass. There should be his custom VC. Something's definitely wrong in the storyboard part.

Comment: Yeah, he/she incorrectly put "Settings" as a view's custom class.

Comment: @NobodyNada UIView>UIButton

Comment: @user3615707 `UIButton` is a built-in class.  Are you using a category or something?

Comment: Yes, The name of my swift file is Settings.swift and my class Settings: UIViewController,MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

Comment: @user3615707 Are you sure you didn't accidentally set a button, for example, as having custom class "Settings" instead of setting the custom class of the view controller?

Comment: @user3615707 - hehe yes...thanks...sorry for the trouble...and thanks to you all!!!

Comment: @user3615707 Oh, cool...so that was the issue then... I'm going to write that out as a proper answer so it's easier for future answer seekers to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sort of error can occur if you accidentally set a view's class to an incompatible custom class; for example, accidentally setting a `UIButton`'s custom class to "Settings," i.e. a `UIViewController` class in this case, may have caused your particular error.

Comment: Note that although this solution worked in this particular case, there are many other possible solutions that may solve similar errors: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725881/unknown-class-myclass-in-interface-builder-file-error-at-runtime , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924966/xcode-6-strange-bug-unknown-class-in-interface-builder-file